# Embedding quicktime player in Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, video, quicktime

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to embed the quicktime player in a cocoa app. The default QTMovieView is kind of ugly, and the quicktime player window has all the features I need in it, such as full screen, and the maintain aspect ratio button.

I'd like it to operate transparently to the user though. I'd rather avoid making them launch the quicktime app. I'd also like to be able to position the window on the screen. Also, I need to be able to access the current playhead position, and capture when they stop the movie. Any ideas on how I might go about doing this? Or would I have to build out my own custom video player?

A third party component would be fine as well if any exist. I'm just looking for that same quicktime player appearance with the black control bar that appears when hovering over the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or would I have to build out my own custom video player?

Yes. There is no (reliable) way of getting QuickTime player to integrate into your application.

You should make a subclass of `QTMovieView`, and maybe use some subviews for the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the controls if the QTMovieView if you do not like them. In IB switch off Show Controller property.

Alternatively, you can use QTMovieLayer.

Also, it is easy to create your own set of controls that will work directly with the properties and methods of the QTMovie.